# Ubuntu 12.10 Help! Everything is incredibly slow

Tags: boot, drivers, 12.10, updates

I installed 12.10 from usb onto this machine.

Intel celeron 2.00 GHz  496MB RAM

I had to modify GNU-Grub to read "nomodeset" or i could not see the GUI. I have an Nvidia graphics card.

Takes about 2 minutes to boot. The icons on the left of desktop take about 1 min to slowly open their menu. Have a network connection but mozilla is 404 and i cannot update.

Where can i find a blow by blow explanation for troubleshooting and repairing this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For older machines with very little ram, you may find Xubuntu or Lubuntu fits better.  As an alternative, consider getting some more recent hardware.  Often times large companies resell 2 year old computers quite cheap.